# Offering a free App that requires an activation code purchased from somewhere else

Tags: android, ios

I have a question regarding a build that we are trying to design.

We have an app that we would like to offer that pulls users content from their account on our partner's site.

The user selects an image they would like to use in the app and purchases it from partner's site.

We create the app and then wait for the user to enter an access code for security since the app is created from personal information/images.

The customer would then go to the app store and download the free app. When the app asks them to enter the activation code purchased on our partner site, we would push the content to them.

Would this work through the Apple store? The content is our partners, the app is for free, their content is accessed through a access code and pushed to the app.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732630/in-app-purchase/10732762#10732762

Answer (score 0):

Apple will reject you.  You would have to use in-app purchase to buy the activation code.  In which case, you might just as well make it a paid app.  (In fact, they probably would reject a free app that required an in-app purchase to do anything.)

Comment: jsd: in principle you are certainly right, however there are often cases in iTunes that proof the opposite. user1345169 Nevertheless, I would certainly follow jsd's advice, since sooner or later someone will report to apple and latest at this stage your app will be removed