# In-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing new app that uses webpage to pay for melody. I don't want to use in-app purchase cause of some reasons. So my questions is : can i use other web-page to pay for melody so user can listhen for this melody. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies) are pretty clear about this:

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected
>
> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>
> 11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app

So the answer is: Yes you can create a web site where a user can purchase melodies that are downloaded to your app. But you are not allowed to mention that web site in your app. Amazons Kindle app does exactly this.

Though, you are not amazon. So you won't sell a lot of melodies when you choose that method.
If your app does not mention the way to get additional melodies people won't open safari to go to your website to figure out if there are more. Just use IAP.

Comment: Thank you! I will think about it and make IAP! but will i pay 30% to apple for every in-app purchase?

Comment: Yes, apple takes 30%. Keep in mind that IAP will sell more content than "go to the not mentioned website, create an account and enter your credit card data". Something like this might work for amazon, but probably not for a small startup or an indie dev. If the content is not very unique or great I for one don't register on websites just to purchase content for an app. Usually it's either IAP or no money from me.

Comment: Hello @MatthiasBauch , this is old post, but proper informative post (+1). I like to add a link to Apple developer, which is properly explained specially for iOS Subscription. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a website for your users to purchase from. You can't redirect your users to your website to purchase items either.

If you don't want to use Apples IAP platform, I would suggest [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/). They have a nice In-App Purchase library. You can use their website to upload your purchasable products.